# Can't perform basic functions on field's text

Tags: sql, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

My goal is to get the length of text and perform other functions on the text that is nested in a Google Big Query field.  The data in question comes from the BQ public dataset: public patents data.  Right now I'm using the BQ console to fetch the data, but in the end I will use an API.

I just want to get the length of the text instead of having to fetch the whole field locally to analyze it, or even to truncate the field at a certain length to make the download feasible.

This query runs, but returns all NULL for all fields except the application_number field.  If I specify WHERE all fields IS NOT NULL, I get the same response. All null fields.

```
SELECT 
-- Get the application number
application_number,
-- Get the length of the claims text
LENGTH(claims_localized[SAFE_OFFSET(0)].text) as claims_length,
-- Get the length of the description text
LENGTH(description_localized[SAFE_OFFSET(0)].text) as description,
-- Get claims truncated at the first double line break
SPLIT(claims_localized_html[SAFE_OFFSET(0)].text, "\n\n")[SAFE_OFFSET(0)] as first_claim_text,
-- Get the number of claims tags in claims html
ARRAY_LENGTH(SPLIT(claims_localized_html[SAFE_OFFSET(0)].text, "<claim>")) as claims_num,
-- Get the number of image tags in claims html
ARRAY_LENGTH(SPLIT(claims_localized_html[SAFE_OFFSET(0)].text, "<figref>")) as drawings_num
-- Specify database
FROM `patents-public-data.patents.publications_201909` 
-- Specify not NULL claims text
WHERE claims_localized[SAFE_OFFSET(0)].text IS NOT NULL
LIMIT 1000
```

What am I doing wrong here to collect the data from these fields?

Here is what I get for results from the BQ console. It always NULL even when I specify the results not be NULL.
[image]

Comment: If I run your query as is, no changes, i do get back real result, where, for example, for application: US-1207579-A
I get back claims length as: 1458 and so on.

Comment: What? I don't get data in the results.  I will add image to the main OP. I do all the columns have data? T.T

Answer (score 1):

TT: I don't have a way to add an image to comment so i will add it in here, take a look: Nothing from your query is changed here and I still see the results perfectly okay. `"May be try unchecking 'Use cache results' in your query settings and try again, it might be something that u run before which is stuck in cache/memory"`

[image]